# Lucene library up gradation from 2.0 to 3.6

Tags: lucene

In my application I have requirement of upgrading lucene core jar from 2.0 to 3.6, the problem is in 2.0 RAMDirectory class was used to read and write files on disk location as well. But in 3.6 RAMDirectory class initialize method signature is changed to take no arguments.
To read the input files from std location on disk I passed FSDirectory.open(File) parameter, but the output index files are not getting written to the location I have provided.

Any idea what needs to be considered while upgrading jar from 2.0 to upper version.

Any reference or experience would be very much helpful.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of `RAMDirectory`.  It makes a complete copy in memory of the index directory passed in.  Changes made to the in memory index will not change the index stored on disk.  Unless there is something I'm missing, this has not changed.  If you wish the makes changes to the stored index, `RAMDirectory` is not really the right class.  You can simply use the `FSDirectory` you've created, instead.

Perhaps your application was loading the RAMDirectory, working with it in memory, and then writing it back to disk later?